# 100 is showing as 10,000% NumberTextBox

Tags: dojo

I set the constraint to use type set to percent, a value of 100 is showing up as 10,000% once the NumericTextbox renders

```
<div id="Percentage" data-dojo-type="ourcompay.NumberTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{type: 'percent'}" title="Percentage" required="true"></div>
```

Not sure what to do to fix this.  Is this a bug with Dojo or I'm not doing something right?  Not quite sure.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `type: 'percent'`? Why not just use a normal number box with a % rendered next to it?

Comment: I could be then I'd have to code a custom widgit, if I can just use percent why go through the hastle.

Comment: ... seriously? adding a percent sign is hassle? Seems to me like you're going to much more hassle with `type: 'percent'` which is clearly meant for displaying decimal values as percents, but editing as decimals...

Comment: @David yup, reverted to creating my own widget :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that given a percentage is a representation of the amount of something in hundreths of a unit that it's doing exactly what it intends - i.e. if you are supplying a value of 100 and expecting that to mean 100% you're not understanding what percentages are.

1 would be 100%.

Comment: the problem is, it's entered as the percent itself.  Not for example 1.  So the value coming back from the DB is 100 standing for 100 percent.  I guess I need to force a divide by 100 before setting the value to the widget?

Comment: Sounds like the simplest solution to me unless there's a scale property on the type that is designed to deal with this sort of scenario. (Not familiar with dojo but I've seen this done in other things).

Comment: I wonder if /100 would screw up precision though...we assume we can just divide by 100 but is that safe to assume and do so?  Just wondering if any possible side effects as we don't know how the 100 was calculated if that is a straight up value coming from the DB.

Comment: If you're lucky your language may have a decimal type and if you use that you shouldn't have any problems there. This type of number representation is often used for text boxes so hopefully you're set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type